# Transfer ERC20 Token - Encountered during contract execution [Reverted]

Tags: contract-development, tokens, erc-20, revert-opcode, transferfrom

When trying to sent some ERC20 Token from wallet getting following error:

```
 Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted]
```

This error returned when i call `transferFrom()`( I made `approve()` before it ) and `transfer()`. Furthermore, I have of lot gas/token amount of my addresses/wallets.

Smart 
Contract code :

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.7;

contract ERC20 {
   //core ERC20 functions
  function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint remaining);
  function approve(address _spender, uint _value)  public returns (bool success);
  function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint balance);
  function totalSupply() public view returns (uint);
  function transfer(address _to, uint _value) public returns (bool success);
  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) public returns (bool success);
// logging events
  event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint _value);
  event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint  _value);
}

contract Transfer  {
    ERC20 public token;
    uint public balance = 0;
    address public owner;
    constructor (address _tokenAddress) public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        token = ERC20(_tokenAddress);
    }

    function() payable external {
        balance += msg.value;
    }

    function transferETH(address payable _to, uint256 _value) public onlyOwner returns (bool){
        _to.transfer(_value);
        return true;
    }

    function transferEth2Many(address payable[] memory _receivers, uint[] memory _values) public onlyOwner returns (bool) {
        require(_receivers.length == _values.length && _receivers.length >= 1);
        for (uint j = 0; j < _receivers.length; j++) {
            _receivers[j].transfer(_values[j]);
        }
        return true;
    }

    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint) {
        return token.totalSupply();
    }

    function balanceOf(address who) public view returns (uint) {
        return token.balanceOf(who);
    }

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint){
        return token.allowance(_owner, _spender);
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint _value) public returns (bool success){
        return token.approve(_spender, _value);
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint _value) public returns (bool success) {
        return token.transfer(_to, _value);
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) public returns (bool success) {
        return token.transferFrom(_from, _to, _value);
    }

    function TransferOne2Many(address[] memory _receivers, uint[] memory _values) public onlyOwner returns (bool) {
        require(_receivers.length == _values.length && _receivers.length >= 1);
        for (uint j = 0; j < _receivers.length; j++) {
            token.transfer(_receivers[j], _values[j]);
        }
        return true;
    }

    function TransferFromOne2Many(address _from, address[] memory _receivers, uint[] memory _values) public onlyOwner returns (bool) {
        require(_receivers.length == _values.length && _receivers.length >= 1);
        for (uint j = 0; j < _receivers.length; j++) {
            token.transferFrom(_from, _receivers[j], _values[j]);
        }
        return true;
    }

    function TransferFromMany2one(address[] memory _froms, address _receiver, uint[] memory _values) public onlyOwner returns (bool) {
        require(_froms.length == _values.length && _froms.length >= 1);
        for (uint j = 0; j < _froms.length; j++) {
            token.transferFrom(_froms[j], _receiver, _values[j]);
        }
        return true;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please verify your contract on etherscan.

Comment: @goodvibration Is it required? Should working without verification?

Comment: It is required for us in order to investigate the transaction that you've linked in your question.

Comment: @goodvibration Look  https://etherscan.io/address/0x812a27078f0644b5bb88d5c0b9d616eb3550bcec#code

Comment: You're not telling the truth when you say "This error returned when i call `transferFrom()`"!!!

Comment: You're also not telling the truth about your smart contract code directly below the other "non-truth telling"!

Comment: @goodvibration I don't understand. I publish new smart contract ( completed ).  This is failed transaction ( transfer from ) from contract. https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2232fc29d4d613379c9fcb5658f5c9c52fb9e0dea43e5bb2f0cac3f5811432ce

Comment: In the transaction that you've linked in your question, function `TransferFromMany2one` was executed.

Comment: @goodvibration TransferFromMany2one executed transferFrom, doesn't matter. Do yo know where the problem is ?

Comment: Yes it does. You need to provide exact details if you're expecting others to be able to investigate **your** problems!

Comment: @goodvibration I shared code of smart code and transaction error. What else ? I deployed smart contract.  Function approve(), allowance(), balanceOf working properly. I have transaction error when trying to execute transfer, transferFrom, TransferFromMany2one. The constructor parameter is adress of ERC20 Token contract.

Comment: The transaction linked in your question shows that function `TransferFromMany2one` was executed (and reverted). Where is the code of that function in your question???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106344/discussion-between-pawelnbd1992-and-goodvibration).

Comment: @goodvibration I edited post.
I have a problem with all the methods associated with the transfer of tokens

Comment: Can you please post an etherscan-link to the reverted transaction?

Comment: @goodvibration https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2232fc29d4d613379c9fcb5658f5c9c52fb9e0dea43e5bb2f0cac3f5811432ce look

Comment: I've answered your question, but looking deeper into your contract, it seems to be using a non-ERC20-standard token, which would cause revert when calling `transfer`, `transferFrom` and `approve` via a standard ERC20 interface. These "bad" tokens were mostly deployed at the early days of the blockchain, before developers have realized the importance of conforming to the standard. I'll extend my answer to address that issue after you confirm reading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the [etherscan-link](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2232fc29d4d613379c9fcb5658f5c9c52fb9e0dea43e5bb2f0cac3f5811432ce) that you have posted in a comment to your own question:

```
From: 0x87ee3337108a31ab539e244f3d22f4070f03d12a
To: Contract 0x812a27078f0644b5bb88d5c0b9d616eb3550bcec

Function: transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value)

[0]:  00000000000000000000000018c7abf493c747f39ce006abeb9bd6d2592e833e
[1]:  000000000000000000000000b7a5329bcb48308e3fba671dfe7e0f6477b1f759
[2]:  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000186a0
```

This is what we have here:

- Sender `0x87ee3337108a31ab539e244f3d22f4070f03d12a`
- Has called a function in contract `0x812a27078f0644b5bb88d5c0b9d616eb3550bcec`
- In an attempt to transfer `0x186a0` (100000) tokens
- From `0x18c7abf493c747f39ce006abeb9bd6d2592e833e`
- To `0xb7a5329bcb48308e3fba671dfe7e0f6477b1f759`

For this transfer to complete successfully, each one of the following must hold:

1. `contract.balanceOf(from)` must be >= 100000
2. `contract.allowance(from, sender)` must be >= 100000

Checking the above conditions [on etherscan](https://etherscan.io/address/0x812a27078f0644b5bb88d5c0b9d616eb3550bcec#readContract):

1. `contract.balanceOf(from) == 1600000 >= 100000`
2. `contract.allowance(from, sender) == 0 < 100000`

The 1st condition holds, but the 2nd condition does not hold.

In order for that condition to hold, `from` must call `contract.approve(sender, 100000)` beforehand.

---

**UPDATE**

The [ERC20 Token Standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) dictates that functions `transfer`, `transferFrom` and `approve` should return `true` for success and `false` for failure.

However, various ERC20 tokens deployed on the network have not implemented this requirement.

[Your contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x812a27078f0644b5bb88d5c0b9d616eb3550bcec#readContract) appears to be using [one such token](https://etherscan.io/address/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7#code).

Calling a function which doesn't return anything using an interface of it which returns `bool` causes the transaction to revert.

Calling a function which returns `bool` using an interface of it which doesn't return anything doesn't cause the transaction to revert.

See a coding example for both cases in [an answer that I have posted to my own question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/78376).

The first (unfortunate) case among these two is exactly what happens in your contract:

```
contract ERC20 {
    ...
    function approve(address _spender, uint _value) public returns (bool success);
    function transfer(address _to, uint _value) public returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) public returns (bool success);
    ...
}

contract Transfer {
    ERC20 public token;
    uint public balance = 0;
    address public owner;
    constructor (address _tokenAddress) public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        token = ERC20(_tokenAddress);
    }

    ...

    function approve(address _spender, uint _value) public returns (bool success) {
        return token.approve(_spender, _value);
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint _value) public returns (bool success) {
        return token.transfer(_to, _value);
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) public returns (bool success) {
        return token.transferFrom(_from, _to, _value);
    }

    ...
}
```

A quick solution would be to modify your `ERC20` interface and get rid of the `returns (bool)` in the declaration of functions `transfer`, `transferFrom` and `approve`.

If you cannot modify that interface directly, then just declare another interface:

```
contract NonStandardERC20 {
    function approve(address _spender, uint _value) public;
    function transfer(address _to, uint _value) public;
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) public;
}
```

And cast each relevant function-call in your code as follows:

- `NonStandardERC20(token).approve(...);`
- `NonStandardERC20(token).transfer(...);`
- `NonStandardERC20(token).transferFrom(...);`

Comment: Thanks ! After yours suggestions all works fine.

Comment: This is answer : Calling a function which doesn't return anything using an interface of it which returns bool causes the transaction to revert.

Calling a function which returns bool using an interface of it which doesn't return anything doesn't cause the transaction to revert.

Comment: @pawelnbd1992: Why did you undo this??? Has the answer "unsolved" your problem in any way? I have spent a tremendous amount of effort in this one, so there should be a very good reason for you to un-accept it after stating that it has solved your problem!

Comment: The error still exists for TransferOne2Many(), TransferFromOne2Many() ,  TransferFromMany2one() methods (transfer and transferFrom working good). For example : when I called TransferOne2Many - the transaction will be approved but I transfer not executed ( logs empty)  https://etherscan.io/tx/0x567b1576429ec9ba69d300e7103fd265dcb8b6aa8ff1d17e9e351166128fc99b

Comment: @pawelnbd1992: Are you kidding me??? This transaction has completed successfully without reverting. The fact that the results are not what you're expecting has nothing to do with the problem described in **this** question, where the transaction **has** reverted! If you have another problem, then you should post it as a separate question, not change the terms of the current question and un-accept an answer which has solved the original problem!!!

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. If you want look at this post https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82228/for-loop-for-transferfrom