# For loop for transferFrom

Tags: tokens, erc-20, transferfrom

`transferFrom` method from ERC20 contract interface:

```solidity
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) public;
```

`transferFrom` function from my contract :

```solidity
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) public returns (bool) {
  token.transferFrom(_from, _to, _value);
  return true;
}
```

`transferFromOneToMany` function with for loop transferFrom function

```solidity
function transferFromOneToMany(address _from, address[] memory _receivers, uint[] memory _values) public onlyOwner returns (bool) {
  require(_receivers.length == _values.length && _receivers.length >= 1);
  for (uint j = 0; j < _receivers.length; j++) {
    token.transferFrom(_from, _receivers[j], _values[j]);
  }
  return true;
}
```

`transferFrom` function working good, I received confirmation of the transaction ( event Transfer )

`transferFromOneToMany` doesn't working good, I received success but transaction don't have events of transfer 
e.g [0x501d19e013defcc6cc1808f75ea0cca575ab8bfb26d96a1869b4671da743e44b](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x501d19e013defcc6cc1808f75ea0cca575ab8bfb26d96a1869b4671da743e44b)

Comment: `but transaction don't have events of transfer` - how exactly have you concluded that? (etherscan wouldn't show you events in either case AFAIK).

Comment: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa9b8ebe321f46ba519008ba9f4db1acbb3a7f49bd53f0806f87f4e50d9c7a69b for example this is correct transaction - I have the event logs tab with 2 transfer event

Comment: I believe that's just a limitation of etherscan, since these events are emitted from the same contract that you send your transaction to (an ERC20 Token contract), while in the other case, you send the transaction to your own contract which doesn't emit any events directly.

Comment: But the real problem is that funds are not transferred from one account to another. Further more now when I added transferFromOneToMany() function to contract, transferFrom() function was failed with error : Bad instruction e.g. https://etherscan.io/tx/0x061bfdfea1357e99d069501a94670657212de7d9fabb55e6251b92ca6173e2ba    Code of contract : https://pastebin.com/bwr8TiBJ

Comment: Could you show what `token` is and how `token.transferFrom(_from, _to, _value)` is implemented?

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov link to code https://pastebin.com/bwr8TiBJ  token is standard of ERC20 , constructor parameter is address of USTD contract

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two major problems with your code that could explain why it doesn't work, but to now it for sure, I need source code of the smart contract referred by the `token` variable.  Here are the problems:

1. You ignore value returned by `token.transferFrom` function.  It is possible that the returned value if `false` in some cases, which means failed transfer.
2. Your `transferFrom` function does not have any access control, which means that anybody may call it at steal the tokens.

While the second problem cannot lead to a failed transfer by itself, it makes me think that you misunderstand how `transferFrom` function is working.  Here is the scenario:

1. Alice calls `transferFrom` on your smart contract asking it to transfer some tokens from Bob to Carol.
2. Your smart contract calls token smart contract asking it to transfer tokens from Bob to Carol.
3. For token smart contract this call is not related to Alice in any way, as the call is originated from your smart contract, not from Alice's address.
4. Token smart contract ensures, that Bob allowed **your smart contract** to take Bob's tokens.
5. Token smart contract transfer tokens from Bob to Carol.
6. Token smart contract reduces the number of tokens **your smart contract** is allowed to take from Bob.

I assume that at steps 4 and 6, there should be **Alice** instead of **your smart contract**, for the whole schema to work properly.  In current implementation, anybody may call `transferFrom` function of your smart contract asking to transfer Bob's token to arbitrary address, and, as Alice's address is never validated, the tokens will effectively be stolen.

So, failed transfer in your case may be caused by the fact that Bob allows Alice to take his tokens, while token smart contract checks whether Bob allowed your smart contract to take them.

OK.  I looked into your transaction and it seems that you've passed the following values to `transferFromOneToMany`:

```
_from: 0x18c7abf493c747f39ce006abeb9bd6d2592e833e
_receivers: [
  0xb7a5329bcb48308e3fba671dfe7e0f6477b1f759,
  0xb7a5329bcb48308e3fba671dfe7e0f6477b1f759
]
_values: [949999, 50000]
```

Address of your contract is `0x14a108a349cde4cb9019672f2489b003dc393049`.
Addres of token smart contract is `0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7`
You've sent transaction from the following address: `0x11b202de5b68ea66610b571b028dcca7743b64bc` and this address is the owner of your smart contract.

So, for your transfers to succeed, the owner of `_from` address should have allowed your smart contract to take at least 999999 tokens.  However, actual allowance for `_owner: 0x18c7abf493c747f39ce006abeb9bd6d2592e833e` and `_spender: 0x14a108a349cde4cb9019672f2489b003dc393049` is zero.  This is why your transfers fail.

Comment: Please check out the contract that this dude is using, following [this transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x061bfdfea1357e99d069501a94670657212de7d9fabb55e6251b92ca6173e2ba), which he posted in a comment to his previous question. This contract uses a non-ERC20-standard token (deployed a while ago), which does not return anything in its `transfer`, `transferFrom` and `approve` functions. Subsequently, this user cannot rely on the returned values of these functions.

Comment: His `token` variable relies on an interface, in which these functions aren't returning anything.

Comment: This does not mean, that real token smart contract, referred by the `token` variable don't return anything.  I would prefer to look at its source code.

Comment: Here is [his previous question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82158/transfer-erc20-token-encountered-during-contract-execution-reverted).

Here is [the specific transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2232fc29d4d613379c9fcb5658f5c9c52fb9e0dea43e5bb2f0cac3f5811432ce) mentioned in a comment to that question.

Here is [his contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x812a27078f0644b5bb88d5c0b9d616eb3550bcec#readContract) used in that transaction.

And here is [the token](https://etherscan.io/address/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7#code) used in that contract.

Comment: You can check out this token and see for yourself.

Comment: The assumption is that in all of these old tokens which were deployed without conforming to the standard, if the transfer should fail for any reason, then the transaction reverts (via `require` or similar). BTW, the exact same behavior applies to pretty much every ERC20 token which **does** conform to the standard (i.e., these functions either revert, or return `true`).

Comment: Anyways, checking the returned value of any of these functions, when you work with tokens deployed by other people, is very tricky. Calling a function which doesn't return anything using an interface of it which returns `bool` causes the transaction to revert.

Comment: @goodvibration Do you have any idea why the transferFrom() function doesn't work in a loop?

Comment: @pawelnbd1992: It needs to be investigated. I haven't read the rest of this answer, which may well explain it (I just read the part about checking returned values, which I have explained to you in an answer on your previous question).

Comment: @goodvibration I believe in you and I wonder how it is possible that the implementation of additional method ( transferFromOneToMany)  causes an error for the transferFrom() function

Comment: Just added more details about your particular transaction.

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov Actual allowance for `_owner` and `_spender`  is 100000000000. Transfer transaction has a status of success but the funds are not transferred.

Comment: What happens if I want to call a smart contract method that doesn't exist?  I trying to execute funcion `TransferFromOne2Many()`, but I but I noticed that in the auto generated code from web3j i have `public static final String FUNC_TRANSFERFROMONE2MANY = "transferFromOne2Many";`  shouldn't be
"TransferFromOne2Many" ?

Comment: Function name affects function selector (first 4 bytes of transaction data).
Selector for `TransferFromOne2Many(address,address[],uint256[])` is `0x0a0e7926`
Selector for `transferFromOne2Many(address,address[],uint256[])` is `0x98336f90`
So your transaction tries to call `transferFromOne2Many` while code in pastebin defines `TransferFromOne2Many`.

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov How do you decompile binary code?[Input Data]